# How does selenium work with hosting services?

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, hosting

I have a Flask app that uses selenium to get data from a website. I have spent 10+ hours trying to get heroku to work with it, but no success. My main problem is selenium. with heroku, there is a "buildpack" that you use to get selenium working with it, but with all the other hosting services, I have found no information. I just would like to know how to get selenium to work with any other recommended service than heroku. Thank you.

Comment: With digitalocean ubuntu droplet after installing needed dependencies works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need hosting service that able to install `Chrome`, `chromedriver` and other dependencies. Find for Virtual Private hosting (VPS), or Dedicated Server or Cloud Hosting but **not** Shared hosting.